# How to line up the bullet text properly?

Tags: html, iphone

I used a coffee bean image as a bullet and set up margins for it. It works on desktop and Android but not on an iPhone... Don't know why, can someone please help? Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a list style image to your css. This changes the list dots with the image you want.

```
li{
    list-style-image: url('[URL to your coffe beans image]');
}
```

This should work on most modern browsers and also with the safari browser in IOS.

If this wasn't your problem some more explaination would be nice :-)